What insects are in this plant pot?
I managed to take a high resolution picture and zoomed it in to show the shape. They are not longer than 1mm at the real scale. They probably got in through some contaminated compost as also mushrooms seem to be present in the same pot.
I have seen fungus gnats flying around but these don't look like them at all.
Now with measurement for scale:


Have no fear. As a UK resident myself, we do not have termites in Britain.
They are called springtails and are a quite harmless little insect and they are used a lot in terrariums since they are regarded as cleaners - they chomp through rotting plant material (not living tissue) and can also be a handy little helping hand at eating larvae.
Terrarium owners can pay about £5 a punnet for these little fellas. They die off as often as they appear and they might have been living in some compost or even blown in on the wind from outside, but they are the good guys and no threat to you or your houseplants.
If you fancy doing a terrarium, scooping up a few springtails to put in with the substrate is a positive move. They are also found in worm bins particularly in the summer. They will also eat fungus gnat larvae.

To me, this look like Termite. Another one here.
I feel them notorious, whatever good they do to the soil or anything else. Just keep them far away from your home. They love moist, damp. They destroy wood, anything related to wood. You will never know the wood underneath is gone, because it will look okay from outside They will decor you room walls without charging you.

Moreover, it is extremely hard,  like next to impossible once they infest your house. So, I don't know what to say.
:(

Added a picture with the scale, that indicates these are too small to be termites (which seem to be at least 4mm long). Also, I'm in the UK where it seems termites are not present: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2021/dec/21/a-world-first-devon-calls-victory-in-27-year-war-on-termites
